# Push Notification iphone (my device not receive notification)

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am facing the problem that my iOS device does not receive any push notification(s).

### Objective-C

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
        UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
      )
     ];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(str);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    UIAlertView *dataAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Device Token"
                                                        message:@"data"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [dataAlert show];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);
    NSString *deviceTokenString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    UIAlertView *deviceTokenAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Device Token"
                                                               message:deviceTokenString
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [deviceTokenAlert show];
}
```

### PHP

```
<?php
$deviceToken = "a448b8946a5de3801dc6a11862a5a0bf11f1adc16xxxxxxxxxxxx"; // masked for security reason
// Passphrase for the private key
$pass = 'molik';

// Get the parameters from http get or from command line
$message = $_GET['message'] or $message = $argv[1] or $message = 'Test Message';
//$badge = (int)$_GET['badge'] or $badge = (int)$argv[2] or $badge  = 1;
$sound = $_GET['sound'] or $sound = $argv[3] or $sound  = 'default';

// Construct the notification payload
$body = array();
$body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);
if ($badge)
    $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
if ($sound)
    $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;


/* End of Configurable Items */
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
// assume the private key passphase was removed.
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);

// for production change the server to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:219
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
    print "Failed to connect $err $errstr\n";
    return;
}
else {
    print "Connection OK\n";
}

$payload = json_encode($body);
$msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
print "sending message :" . $payload . "\n";



$result=fwrite($fp, $msg);

echo $result;
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**When the PHP code is run it shows the output:**

```
Connection OK sending message :{"aps":{"alert":"Test Message","sound":"default"}}
```

But on the device side, no notifications are received.

Comment: Check the ray wenderlich push notification tutorial you will get your answer. Sorry but that site is not loading from my place other wise i would have given you the link. Or you can also google for it.

Comment: There is no error logged when launching your app? Also, use APNS-PHP, much better when using PHP for sending push notifications: http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/

Comment: hello robin thanx for reply . i have study this tutorial but i am not understand where my mistake. every thing is ok but iphone device not receive notification.

Comment: Did you create your provisioning profiles before or after you created your APNS Certificates? Did you update your profiles after your created the APNS cert? If not, try it. Otherwise the profiles won't know about the push service. Also, did you get the "This application wants to send push notifications" question on your device? + As Robin wrote: Start ACCEPTING answers on your other questions! Not nice not accepting!

Comment: You may also want to check that port 5223 is open to your device in the network you're connecting to.

Comment: hello  onnoweb thanx for reply . i have download ipuser application from app store for testing it work fine in my iphone device

Comment: Hello friend i have fixed this problem . I have changed Development Push SSL Certificate to Production Push SSL Certificate and change 

Development Push SSL Certificate
to
Production Push SSL Certificate

Comment: thanx paul but i am facing new problem i am not receiving feedback

Comment: in this i am using same ck.pem file .

Comment: please check my php code :<?php
$pass='molik';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
 stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);
// production server is ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
// production server is ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196

Comment: $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://feedback.push.apple.com:2196', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
if (!$fp) {
    print "Failed to connect feedback server: $err $errstr\n";
    return;
}
else {
   print "Connection to feedback server OK\n";
}
 print "APNS feedback results\n  ";

Comment: while ($devcon = fread($fp, 38))
      {
   $arr = unpack("H*", $devcon); 
   $rawhex = trim(implode("", $arr));
  $feedbackTime = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 0, 8)); 
   $feedbackDate = date('Y-m-d H:i', $feedbackTime); 
  $feedbackLen = hexdec(substr($rawhex, 8, 4)); 
  $feedbackDeviceToken = substr($rawhex, 12, 64);
  print "TIMESTAMP:" . $feedbackDate . "\n";
         print "DEVICE ID:" . $feedbackDeviceToken. "\n\n";
 }
fclose($fp);
?>

Comment: Next time please edit your question instead of putting all that in the comments. BTW the tutorial mentioned earlier is at http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Answer (score 2):

I faced lot of problems related to public and private key.

At last I had revoked all certificates and followed the below link and then I'm getting the push notification in device.

You can also find the sample code of php in the below [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your certificates. Try to create the new app id and generate the development.cer`and`production.cer`. After that generate provisioning profiles.